# Reopen review queue showing wrong revision message?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I was reviewing the reopen queue and encountered [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18922686).

I saw that the post was added to the queue because it was edited, and the diff is shown to me. I can also see the revision summary being this:

> If you want to complain, go to the meta site.

However, I don't see how this revision summary relates to the diff. The diff just seems to reword the question. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

So I clicked on the "link" button on the right and then went to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48963868/revisions) of the question. I see that the displayed diff is from revision 3, so I guess it is revision that triggered the question to be put into the queue. However, the revision message seems to be from revision 4, where a complaint from the OP is removed.

Is this a bug that the revision message and the diff do not match? (I didn't tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) just in case it isn't.)

Comment: The two revisions were combined (e.g. it's displaying the *current* state of the question compared to its state from before it was closed). You'll notice that the diff you're seeing doesn't include the paragraph that was edited out later. So it's more an issue of which revision comment *should* we display there when it's pulling changes from multiple revisions?

Comment: @animuson Oh I see what's happened here now! Why display the revision summary at all? Since the diff is showing a combination of all the revisions, showing any one revision summary has a high chance of being irrelevant to the diff.

Comment: Or show all of the revision summaries and link them to the specific revisions.